# How to enable permanent editing of Gmail "To" field

Tags: gmail, email, gmail-text-editor

In a recent gmail update, google disables editing the email addresses in the "To" field  unless you click a context menu. Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 1):

##### Directly Edit email address

You can directly edit an email address via a keyboard shortcut:

1. Select the email address
   Use whatever method you choose: Mouse click, **<kbd>backspace</kbd>**, <kbd>◀</kbd>, <kbd>▲</kbd>,  <kbd>▶</kbd>, <kbd>▼</kbd>, etc.
2. Press **<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**
3. Change whatever characters you wish.